# Inserting external image into PowerPoint with officer without changing image dimensions

Tags: r, officer

Is it possible to insert external images into a Powerpoint with `officer` without changing the image dimensions?

This is the code I have now where `x` is an `rpptx` object:

```r
library(officer)
image_url <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/768px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png"
 t_file <- tempfile(pattern = "logo_", fileext = ".png")
 download.file(image_url, destfile = t_file)
 x <- x %>%
    ph_with(value = external_img(t_file), location = ph_location(left = 9.4, top = 4.6))
```

This will change the dimensions of the image to 4x3 inches (the default for `ph_location()`).

I know you can use external R packages to get image metadata then pass this to the function so the actual image dimensions are used, but I don't want to add any more external R package dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always specify the image dimensions within your `external_img` function. I'm assuming you know what dimensions you want, so say your dimensions are width = 9, height = 5 it would look something like this:

```
    library(officer)
image_url <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/768px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png"
 t_file <- tempfile(pattern = "logo_", fileext = ".png")
 download.file(image_url, destfile = t_file)
 x <- x %>%
#specify height and width
    ph_with(value = external_img(t_file, width = 9, height = 5), location = ph_location(left = 9.4, top = 4.6))
```

Hope that is helpful!